# Show soft upgrade or share review again after user declines upgrade

Tags: java, google-play

I am beginner in Native Java for android.
I would like to know how I can ask the user to update the app again only after the days I choose?
Currently when the user clicks cancel a soft update, the app asks for the update again after the user enters the App, and this is annoying. Please, can someone help me?

How can I do this for IN-APP-REVIEW as well?
When the user declines an evaluation within flow(), I ask for an evaluation again after X days..

Review Code Flow:

```
  void activateReviewInfo()
  {
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(() -> {
      manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);

      Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
      request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          reviewInfo = task.getResult();
          Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo);

          flow.addOnCompleteListener(result -> {
          });
        }
      });

      request.addOnFailureListener(e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage()));
    }, 15000);
  }
```

In-App-Update

```
  private ReviewInfo reviewInfo;
  private ReviewManager manager;

  private static final int RC_APP_UPDATE = 100;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    if (new ReviewsManager().getDaysAppInstaled(this) >= 7) {
      activateReviewInfo();
    }
    activateUpdate();
  }

  void activateUpdate(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(() -> {
      AppUpdateManager mAppUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
      Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = mAppUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

      appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(result -> {
        if (result.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                && result.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
          try {
            mAppUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(result, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, MainActivity.this, RC_APP_UPDATE);
          } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }

        }
      });
      mAppUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
    }, 9000);
  }

  private final InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener = installState -> {
    if (installState.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
      showCompleteUpdate();
    }
  };

  private void showCompleteUpdate() {
    AppUpdateManager mAppUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Atualização pronta para ser Instalada...",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

    snackbar.setAction("Instalar", view -> mAppUpdateManager.completeUpdate());

    snackbar.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_APP_UPDATE && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

  private void installAppIfHaveDownload () {
    AppUpdateManager mAppUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    mAppUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
      if(appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
        showCompleteUpdate();
      }
    });
  }

  private void unregisterListenerIfAppIsInstalled () {
    AppUpdateManager mAppUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    mAppUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
      if(appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.INSTALLED) {
        mAppUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
      }
    });
  }

@Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterListenerIfAppIsInstalled();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    installAppIfHaveDownload();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    reviewInfo = null;
    manager = null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is call:

```
if(task.isCanceled()) {
 /// code
}

OR 

if(appUpdateInfo.installStatus() === InstallStatus.CANCELED){
 /// code..
/// if ok call showCompleteUpdate();
}
```

But i do know how to do here :/ i'm beginner in java.
do i just need to call the function to activate the evaluation flow or refresh again after x days? How can I do this calculation and what do I need to do?